# Logout Action is not working after reloading Angular Page

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store-4.0

**PROBLEM:**

After login to the app when I click on `signOut` button, it successfully `signOut` and redirect to login page. But when I refresh a page then try signing out then it will do nothing. Anyone knows what can be issue?

**CODE:**

```js
// action
export class Logout implements Action {
  readonly type = LOGOUT;
}

// effect
@Effect()
  logout$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(authAction.LOGOUT)
    .pipe(
      map( () => {
        debugger;
        this.authService.logoutUser();
        return new fromRoot.Go({
          path: ['/account/login'],
        });
      })
  );

// calling action on signout 
public signOut() {      
      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.Logout());
    }
```

**SCREENSHOT of Chrome Redux DevTools**

Before refreshing the page: 
http://prntscr.com/ne3pc0

After refreshing the page: 
http://prntscr.com/ne3qpr (There is nothing after Logout Action)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';    
// effect
@Effect()
logout$ = this.actions$.pipe(
.ofType(authAction.LOGOUT),
switchMap(() => {
    return this.authService.logoutUser()
        .pipe(map(() => {
            return new fromRoot.Go({path: ['/account/login']})
         }), 
         catchError((error: any) =>{
            return of(error)    
         }), 
         finalize(() => {
            //do something like hide loader
         }))
  })  
);
```

let me know in case of any issue

Comment: It would be worth adding some explanation as to why you believe this will work. Also I think you meant to say `.pipe(map(() => ...))` presuming rxjs6 is being used

Comment: I have tested it and its working. Also it can be done using .pipe too

Comment: @PawanJangid it's not working. I have tried by adding debugger in the effect but after refreshing the page the control not go inside the effect after action.

Comment: @Johar Zaman: Can you try one scenario Login->Logout->Login->Logout  without refreshing the page...And after that refresh the page and check console for any errors

Comment: @PawanJangid okay i can try

Comment: I have tried this, still nothing happens. And don't have any error in console

Comment: @Johar Zaman: This issue might be related to the Effect being unsubscribed in some case...An ngrx effect is a singleton, once unsubscribed will never subscribe again.

Comment: How can i verify that effect is not being unsubscribed after refresh?

Comment: Does this effect called after refreshing the page in some case or check if logout action dispatched just after page refresh by adding debugger in effect

Comment: @Johar Zaman: You may try handling exceptions in the effect as already suggested in code...  catchError((error: any) =>{return of(error)})                                You should catch the error in the inner observable and return a new non-error observable to prevent effect observable from unsubscribing.